# typescript: generic for addable types? (with `+`)?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

Is there a way in typescript to declare a generic type parameter that ensures a type has addition?

For example, the typechecker objects to the following:

```js
function myAddition<T>(x: T, y: T) {
  // Typechecker error: Operator '+' cannot be applied to types 'T' and 'T'.
  return x + y;
}
```

How do I declare my generic type `T` to tell the typechecker that this function can only be called on types that can be added?

Comment: No, there's no way to do that. But partly because anything can be added, just not necessarily with useful results.

Comment: Are you trying to support both addition `1+2` and concatenation `"a" + "b"`? What about string coercion `"a" + [1,2,3]`? You could argue that "added" only applies to numbers, in which case the only valid type for `T` is just `number`.

Comment: Certainly looking to support both `number` and `BigInt`. But I wouldn't mind a broader parameter though (e.g. including strings)